# grails - Could not reserve enough space for object heap

Tags: grails, jvm

I am getting this error running app:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
| Compiling 5 source files
| Compiling 5 source files.....
***
Metrics servlet injected into web.xml
Metrics Admin servlet-mapping (for /metrics/*) injected into web.xml
***
| Running Grails application
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

I looked over the same errors on Stack and made adjustments to the memory but I am still getting this error. I am new to Grails but I believe everything is setup correct and i can run a sample app (helloworld). 
Here is the changes i made:

```
-Xms512m -Xmx1g -XX:PermSize=256m
```

This is the memory

```
free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2015       1297        718         56        169        859
-/+ buffers/cache:        267       1748
```

Checking if parameters are being read

```
$ ps -ef | grep java
tomcat7  32158     1  1 11:02 ?        00:00:10 /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Xms512m -Xmx1g -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xms512m -Xmx1g -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat7/endorsed -classpath /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat7 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat7 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/tomcat7-tomcat7-tmp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

I have this in my $HOME/.profile

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1g -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
```

in my setenv.sh for Tomcat7

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1g \
    -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled \
    -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled \
    -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC \
    -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
```

I am not sure what to change now - it seems the memory would be adequate? Please any thoughts would be great. thank you

Forgot to add if needed:

```
$ grails -version
Grails version: 2.4.5
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_95"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.4) (7u95-2.6.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
```